# pg-promise ColumnSet use Postgres functions with def property

Tags: javascript, pg-promise

I am using a [ColumnSet](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.ColumnSet.html) and the [helper.insert](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html) function for a multi row insert.

I have a table column where I want to use the Postgres [Date/Time now()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html) function.

```
const cs = new helpers.ColumnSet([
    'lastname',
    {
        name: 'rental_date',
        def: 'now()'
    }
], { table: { table: 'book_rental', schema: 'public' } })

let rentals = [
    {
        lastname: 'Mueller'
    },
    {
        lastname: 'Johnson'
    }
]

let insert = helpers.insert(rentals, cs)

db.result(insert)
    .then(data => res.json({ message: 'Ok!' }))
    .catch(err => res.json({ message: 'Not ok!' }))
```

It seems to be working by using `def: 'now()'`, but I want to make sure that I am using it the right way.

**Edit:**

Regarding the answer in the comment. I tried to do the insert manually and it looks like Postgres is converting the `'now()'` string into the `now()` function.

```
INSERT INTO book_rental (lastname, rental_date) VALUES ('Mueller', 'now()');
```

To involve your answer, am I right that this should be the correct code then?

```
const cs = new helpers.ColumnSet([
    'lastname',
    {
        name: 'rental_date',
        mod: ':raw',
        def: 'now()'
    }
], { table: { table: 'book_rental', schema: 'public' } })
```

Comment: `It seems to be working?` Can you be more specific? It looks like it won't work, because you need to use a raw-text string, and not an escaped text string.

Comment: Sorry, I was saying that using the code above and checking the database after the insert, the `rental_date` is stored correctly as `timestamptz`. That is why I thought it is working.

Comment: `def` is only used when the property is missing. If it is not missing, the column value is used instead, so it may be not working. If you want to be sure, you should use `init` instead.

Comment: Your update would indeed resolve one issue. For the other one - see my answer ;)

Comment: You know, that `:raw` inline syntax is even shorter, and works in all versions of the library. Myself, being the author, even I sometimes forget those details :))) After all, I did design it to be ultimately flexible. So I have updated my answer. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't look right, for the following reasons:

- You want to use `now()` without any condition, but the `def` value is only used when the property doesn't exist in the source object (see [Column](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.Column.html)). The `init` callback is what should be used instead to guarantee the right value override.
- You return `now()` as an escaped string, while the query needs it as a raw-text string.

First, let's declare a reusable [Raw Text](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#raw-text) string, as per [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting):

```
const rawText = text => ({toPostgres: () => text, rawType: true});
```

Then you can define the column like this:

```
{
    name: 'rental_date',
    init: () => rawText('now()')
}
```

And make sure you are using the latest version of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) (v7.2.1 as of this writing).

Or alternatively, you can declare it like this:

```
{
    name: 'rental_date',
    mod: ':raw', // same as mode: '^'
    init: () => 'now()'
}
```

This syntax however will work in all versions of the library, and perhaps is even simpler to use ;)

Comment: I know I should not use the comment for just 'thanks'. But I have to say it **Thank you very much!** :)